# What is a nice word to describe someone who is never where they should be?

Tags: single-word-requests

I had a math teacher in grades four through seven who was never in class.

What’s a nice word to describe his lack of presence?

Comment: What words have you discounted, and why?

Comment: Which do you need- A word to describe the person themselves, or to describe their lack of presense?

Comment: You are going to have some trouble coming up with a “nice” (meaning complimentary) word for what is essentially irresponsible and inconveniencing behavior. Are you looking therefore for a euphemism to mask the bad behavior in fakery?

Comment: With the answers all over the map and the comments asking for clarification unadressed, this question is unsustainable in its current form.

Answer (score 5):

[**Peripatetic**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripatetic_school) - notionally means "wandering about" or walking or wandering **but** has overtones of Aristotelian teaching style - teaching while walking. Quite a fun term to use in this context. Wikipedia (link above) says

- " ... "peripatetic" is often used to mean itinerant, wandering, meandering, or walking about. After Aristotle's death, a legend arose that he was a "peripatetic" lecturer – that he walked about as he taught ..."

"Occasional" - while this is meant to mean that he is only sometimes your teacher and not always present at all classes , if he is meant to always be present then the meaning moves towards your required one.

MIA / Missing in action.

Itinerant - not usually used this way BUT conveys the intention when it is obvious that the usual meaning does not apply.

Putative - implication is that they are **meant** to be doing the job, but ...

- Mr Banks, our putative teacher, ...

" ..., When he puts in an appearance ..."

" ... on the occasions that he shows up ..."

Answer (score 5):

> **AWOL, astray, away, elsewhere, ghost, missing, no-show, vanished**.

You can characterize and caricature him by adding "**Mr**" in front of a name:

> **Professor Casper** (the friendly ghost, and for a math teacher to be absent is very friendly),

or an adjective phrase:

> **Mr Out-of-Sight, Mr Unsubstantial, Mr Ethereal, Mr Incorporeal, My Invisible Math Teacher, Mr Wasn't There, Mr Illusory, Mr Imaginary, Mr Manquant (French for "missing"), Mr Missing.**

Answer (score 4):

That depends largely on where those individuals *are*, when they're not where they should be.

These aren't single words, but two expressions I might suggest would be:

- **chronically late** (if they are simply tardy much of the time)
- **chronically lost** (if they never seem to be in the right place at the right time)

The latter of those two can also be expressed using the more humorous ***navigationally challenged***.

Answer (score 2):

> *Absent* teacher or *absentee* teacher.

---

Schoolchildren are described as being *truant* if away from school without good reason. Might this also be attributed to absent teachers?

As a noun and adjective:

> truant

As a verb (BE):

> play truant

[Source](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/truant?region=uk&q=truant).

Answer (score 1):

On the analogy of *absentee landlord* you could call him an *absentee teacher*.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question on what aspect of the professor you really want to describe. But from what you say, he could have been a *derelict* teacher who never showed up in class.